# git log branch1..branch2 (two dots) vs. git log branch1...branch2 (three dots)?

Tags: git, git-branch

I've read the latter compares the branches starting from their ancestor. What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Two dots

```
git log start-branch..end-branch
```

(equivalent to `git log ^start-branch end-branch`).

Lists all the commits reachable from `end-branch` that are not reachable from `start-branch`.

## Three dots

```
git log start-branch...end-branch
```

Lists all commits that are reachable from either `start-branch` *or* `end-branch` *but* not reachable from both `start-branch` *and* `end-branch`.

## References

- [Two and three dots with log](http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/git_log_dots.html)
- [Pro Git Book, *Revision Selection*](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)

Comment: Careful: `git log start-branch..end-branch` is equivalent to `git log ^start-branch end-branch` (note the caret before `start-branch`), not to `git log start-branch end-branch`.

Comment: @jubobs thanks for mentioning that. Can you link to the docs? flafoux, can you update your answer?